# converting to exe and modules suddenly not working

Tags: python, module, exe, pyinstaller

I am using pyinstaller to convert my .py file to exe. 
When I run my py file from the command line, it works perfectly, however when I convert it to .exe using pyinstaller, I get errors on lines containing modules I imported. I understand I may need to edit the spec file, however even with this I am very confused.
Any help here?!?!?! Thanks!

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import fitz
import os
import re
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import email, smtplib, ssl
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email import encoders
import glob
```

Edit:
However, in my code I include

```
#Master PDF to be parsed. Must be in the same folder as 'exe' file 
file_name = glob.glob('.pdf') 
if file_name == []: 
    file_name = glob.glob('.PDF')[0] 
else: 
    file_name = file_name[0]
```

And when I run the exe file, I get index errors on that line.

Answer (score 0):

PyInstaller would handle all the above modules except for `pandas` module which needs to be used with [`Tree`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/advanced-topics.html#the-toc-and-tree-classes) class to bundle lib folder with executable.

I only add the `pandas` Python path (e.g `./env/Lib/site-packages/pandas`) and you need to edit it based on your Python path:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['script.py'],
             pathex=['<project_path>'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
a.datas += Tree("./env/Lib/site-packages/pandas", prefix="pandas")
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='script',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Finally, generate your executable with `pyinstaller script.spec`.

Comment: Thanks. However, in my code I include
```
    #Master PDF to be parsed. Must be in the same folder as 'exe' file
    file_name = glob.glob('*.pdf')
    if file_name == []:
        file_name = glob.glob('*.PDF')[0]
    else:
        file_name = file_name[0]
```
And when I run the exe file, I get index errors on that line

Comment: I am now getting this error
No such file or directory: './env/Lib/site-packages/pandas'

Comment: @user5279 As I said, you should change this path to current python path based on your system. For example, if you install Python on `C:/Program Files/Python37` it would become `C:/Program Files/Python37/Lib/site-packages/pandas`.